# how to provide executable permission to adb binary using bb file

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, adb, yocto

1. After compiling this bb file , instead of using **chmod** i do **not get executable binary**.
2. Please suggest me the changes so that i may get ***executable binary in /usr/bin***

   ```
    FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
    SRC_URI = "file://adb-binary"

    do_install () {
      install -d ${D}/usr/bin/
      cp -r ${WORKDIR}/adb-binary/ ${D}/usr/bin/
      chmod +x ${D}/usr/bin/adb-binary/
    }
    FILES_${PN} += "/usr/bin/"
   ```

   where source file in in

   ```
    ls -l adb/files/adb-binary/
    total 1124
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 Vksingh Vksingh 1150696 Nov 10 01:06 adb
   ```

Answer (score 1):

in the yocto mega manual you can see this good example - https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#new-recipe-single-c-file-package-hello-world

essentially you want the following (from the mega manual):

```
 do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 helloworld ${D}${bindir}
 }
```

you do not want to use chmod manually as that will not transfer over to target. If adb-binary is include with SRC_URI you can use $(WORKDIR)/adb-binary instad of helloworld.

You can also use do_install_append() if you want some other packages to install, and just add this little snippet for adb-binary.